# UITableView not executing to scrollViewDidScroll or scrollViewShouldScrollToTop

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a private table view in my `UIViewController` as follows

```
 UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate> {

 @private
   UITableView *gTableView;
...
}
```

in my implementation i have set

```
gTableView.delegate=self;
gTableView.dataSource=self;
```

**EDIT**

The `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating` and `scrollViewDidScroll` delegates are getting called but not the `scrollViewDidScrollToTop`.

What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Shouldn't you be implementing `UITableViewDataSource` too? Also `UITableViewDelegate` itself conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

Comment: ya i am .. just for SO purpose i gave only the required delegates.. here's what I am implementing :UIActionSheetDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

Comment: well thanks... i guess that was the mistake then.. i shouldn't have implemented both... removing the scroll delegate is now calling "scrollViewDidScroll" but not calling "scrollViewDidScrollToTop" which is not good for me.. any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

When used with a `TableView`, `scrollViewDidScrollToTop` only gets called with a scroll-to-top gesture (a tap on the status bar).  Try using `scrollViewDidEndDragging` or `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` to detect if `scrollView.contentOffset.y` is `<= 0`